# Fill up listbox over method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods, listbox

I'm trying to fill up a listbox over a method. I'd like to do that cause I'll use this method several times in my application.

Here's the way it works:

```
DataTable table = ru.getDataTable("Select UserID, User From tblUser Where tblUser.Archived = false");

            lstBenutzer.DataSource = table;
            lstBenutzer.ValueMember = "UserID";
            lstBenutzer.DisplayMember = "User";
```

I'd like to do it like this:

```
lstBenutzer = getListbox("Select UserID, User From tblUser Where tblUser.Archived = false", "User");

private ListBox getListbox(string query, string tabelle)
        {
            ListBox box = new ListBox();
            DataTable table = ru.getDataTable(query);

            box.DataSource = table;
            box.ValueMember = tabelle + "ID";
            box.DisplayMember = tabelle;

            return box;
        }
```

I don't get any error it just doesn't work.
My listbox "lstBenutzer" stays empty...

What am I doeing wrong?

Comment: Did you debug the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create new instance of `ListBox` control, it will replace the generated control that you create in the design view. Instead of creating new instance, you can pass whole object of your `ListBox` control to your method.

```
private void getListbox(ListBox listBox, string query, string tabelle)
{
            DataTable table = ru.getDataTable(query);

            listBox.DataSource = table;
            listBox.ValueMember = tabelle + "ID";
            listBox.DisplayMember = tabelle;
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
getListbox(lstBenutzer, "Select UserID, User From tblUser Where tblUser.Archived = false", "User");
```

You can also use an extension method to make it available on all object of type `ListBox` control

Answer (score 0):

you gave listBox's value member tabella+ID and in your query there is no such of tabella field. Value member must be unique as you know. For this reason previous code works